# Получение даты обновления антивирусных баз через реестр (kaspersky)

Tags: python, kaspersky

Задача следующая, необходимо вычислить сколько дней прошло с момента обновления антивирусных баз.

Язык программирования python.

Проблема в том, что в каталоге реестра "...\Software\KasperskyLab\protected\KES\watchdog\BaseInfo" Значение с датой имеет вид "Date = 132693620400000000" И как ее в человеческий вид понятия не имею.

К примеру в Eset в ветке Software\ESET\ESET Security\CurrentVersion\Info значение "ScannerVersion" имеет вид "23592 (20210708)" и из него достать дату уже проблем нет.

А как быть с Касперским?

Comment: если предположить, что там нано-секунды с какого-то неизвестного момента времени, то, например, `date -d @$(echo '132693620400000000/1000000000+1490000000' | bc)` возвращает `Thu 03 Jun 2021 07:13:40 AM MSK`. добавьте ещё секунд в слагаемое, чтобы получить какое-то близкое к реальному значение.

Comment: Думаю будет полезна следующая информация. На данный момент значение Date = 132702235800000000, в касперском дата выпуска баз 08.07.2021 19:22

Comment: ну, значит надо добавить ещё 5746100 секунд: `$ date -d @$(echo '132693620400000000/1000000000+1495746100' | bc)` возвращает `Sun 08 Aug 2021 07:22:00 PM MSK` (ну, это исходя из того, что 19:22 — по мск, а не по гринвичу)

Comment: только 8 июля дата, а не августа

Comment: хм. промазал. ну, сами сможете подогнать количество секунд? подсказка: надо отнять 31*24*60*60

Comment: Супер! Получилось, только в python это через команду time.ctime() сделал.